# Adding limit of items displayed in suggestions

Tags: javascript, list, search-suggestion

I am using this pattern to create list of live suggestions. ( https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp ). 
Do you have any idea how can I limit suggested items to 5? I dont wanna see list of 100 items displayed because they match search.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the first 5 items out of the matches array and show that instead of all matches with the [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method.

```js
var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua &amp; Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba"];
var firstFiveCountries = countries.slice(0, 5);
console.log(firstFiveCountries);
```

Comment: Yes, but where exactly should I put it?

Comment: Can't tell without you sharing your code. Show me what you've done and I'll try to help out. Add the JavaScript to your original question.